# Making a graph with different colours

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of corona virus which looks something like this

```
day month cases deaths country
3     5     10    1     USA
4     5     12    2     USA
```

it has multiple entries for each country for different days, I made it filter out so it only gets the data from `28th of May` now I want to make a graph for every country with how many cases they have use pandas and matploitlib

However it's not working properly

when I use

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel("covid.xlsx")
print(df.columns.tolist())
df.loc[(df.day == 28) & (df.month==5), :].plot.line(x='countriesAndTerritories', y='deaths')
plt.show()
```

The code executes but only shows 5 countries and the `countriesAndTerritories` is on the `x` axis, when I switch around `x='countriesAndTerritories', y='deaths'` I get `TypeError: no numeric data to plot`

This is  a reference of what I want: https://qap.ecdc.europa.eu/public/single/?appid=f818d019-18c5-41e0-99e6-bd2b7f6f17b5&obj=3d471628-9a6e-4938-95da-0cba933925ca&opt=nointeraction&select=clearall (europe's data visualization)

Comment: Do you want to reproduce the same plot as in the figure you have linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reproduce the plot with seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
sns.lineplot(data=df.iloc[0:600,:], x='dateRep', y='deaths', hue='countriesAndTerritories')
```

Output:

[image]

Here I selected a subset of the whole dataframe (since there are 200 countries it would be too messy to show the legend).
If you want to select another range, change the 0 and 600 (`df.iloc[0:600,:]`). Or if you have a list of countries you want to plot you can do this:

```
countries_to_plot = ["Zimbabwe", "Italy","France","Netherlands"]
sns.lineplot(data=df[df.countriesAndTerritories.isin(countries_to_plot)], x='dateRep', y='deaths', hue='countriesAndTerritories')
```

Comment: Thanks so much, just wondering, how could I change the subset of countries?

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes me excited for data visualization:)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would like to plot day vs deaths and the country as a legend. Is my understanding correct? If that is the case, you can do something like this:

```
plt.scatter(df['day'], df['deaths'],label= df['country'])
```

Comment: I want a graph with the y axis being the names of the countries (`countriesAndTerritories`) and the x axis being the deaths

Comment: The link you shared has a separate graph for each country. That is not X axis, it seems like a legend of the plot

Comment: Yes the lines are coloured for hte countries on the link but I don't know if this is do-able with pandas.

Comment: See this https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.06-customizing-legends.html